# Printer Samsung SCX-3405 - continue to print after out of paper. Myth or reality?

Tags: printing, printer

If you're so unlucky as I and have this piece of something that is proudly calling Printer (i.e. Samsung SCX-3405) , so you're aware of an issue that after out of paper the device doesn't continue to print.

The only option I have is to reset it (turn off/on) and reprint missing part.

I dream (like I always have with all other printers) if there's a magical button (or combination of them, or even software/firmware solution) that fix this stupid behaviour.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since when this issue persist (did it work correctly before)? From what device do you want to print? Have you tried updating driver?

Comment: It works fine until out of paper. After that it stucks and reset only (see above). I print from pc or osx (the same behaviuor). Latest version of Samsung drivers (at both os).

Comment: again: did you had this issue since the beginning you have the printer? Also, how old is it, (is it still under warranty)?

Comment: Yes. The issue from the very beginning. The printer is about 2+ years old. No warranty AFAIK.

Comment: Every printer I have used (including some Samsungs) will wait until you add more paper. Go through the front panel menu for any relevant settings. Also make sure the Paper Size and Type match the setting from the front panel (System Setup > Paper Setup)

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I've changed source from auto to manual feeder and this fix my issues. Write down you answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same printer, and I was able to fix this issue have irked me for years.

To resume, all you have to do is to open the top part of the printer (The area where the sheats of paper exit, not the scanner lid) I wasn't aware that it was possible to open this at all, because the printer very rarely jam. But when you do and close it again, the printer continues printing.

It is a bit strange, but no combination of buttons have ever worked for me on my printer, and this solution works as a charm every time.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you click Stop/Clear and that makes the printer RESUME once you have loaded paper.
It's totally unintuitive! But I just had the same problem, and that is what worked.